# What do the different colored bars in the query editor menu mean in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

What's the significance of the color change in this picture?
[image]

EDIT: I was referring to the yellow and green areas of the scroll bar.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
Blue  - SQL keywords - query specification components
Pink  - Functions
Grey  - SQL predicates
Black - table/column names/aliases
```

The colored bars on the left, next to the line numbers, appear next to lines that have been changed since opening the file:

```
Yellow - Changed lines that have not been saved
Green  - Changed lines have already been saved
```

Comment: I meant the scroll bar, I'll edit the question.  that was poor planning.

Comment: changed lines in what context?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie - Saved file that has been changed before re-saving.

Comment: much obliged, sir.  i always wandered that.