# Oracle SQL Developer and code/line change indicator

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Does Oracle SQL Developer 4.1 provide an indicator for what lines were changed in the code editor? For example, in SSMS a [yellow vertical bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055378/what-do-the-different-colored-bars-in-the-query-editor-menu-mean-in-ssms) appears next to the line number, whenever new code is added/modified/deleted. This line changes to green after it is saved.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't make a difference for your question, but you should know that 4.1 is pretty old, and SQL Developer has free upgrades, so you'll see a lot of improvements if you move up to say, version 18.4

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Your posts have helped me a ton as I have started to use Oracle SQL Developer more frequently. For work purposes, I remain on this version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of.

You need to toggle over to the History panel for your Code Editor. Then you can see this -

[image]

The revision history 'depth' can be configured in preferences, and a benefit (I think) over SSMS here is that it will track changes over multiple iterations of your file, not just between what happened since 'last save.'

Comment: It took me ages to realise that this only works after you **open** a file. If you save a worksheet to a file you have to close and reopen it before the history tab appears. I was going slightly crazy trying to figure out why I couldn't find anything about local history or revisions in the menus <sigh>

Comment: Of course, I should have just [looked at your blog](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/04/tracking-script-changes-locally-in-oracle-sql-developer/)...

Comment: @AlexPoole the idea is I THINK, that an anon worksheet is like a scratchpad, and we save the formal deltas when more likely to be code in a file, if that makes any sense

Comment: Yes, but having saved the worksheet to a file, I hadn't twigged that it was still treated differently. Which also makes sense, I think. I've seen the history tab but obviously never paid attention to when/why it appears, or investigated it. I don't work from existing files much but it looks worth exploring. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Jeff! Not sure how I missed that tab. You are right about the benefits of extending track changes beyond the last save.